# Separate and group the strings that have # and without #

Tags: vb.net

Separate and group the strings that have `#` and `without #`

`Dim Strfinal as String = "#Cccccc,#Aaaaaa,Aaaaa,Baaaa,Caaaa,#Bbbbbb,Abbbbb,Bbbbbb,Cbbbbb"`

I want the output like this
`#Cccccc, #Aaaaaa(Aaaaa,Baaaa and Caaaa) and #Bbbbbb(Abbbbb,Bbbbbb and Cbbbbb)`

I used this code to separate the character that have no `#`

```
Dim rws As String

If Aaaaa.Checked = True Then
   CheckBox1.Checked = True
   close_parenthesis.Checked = True

   If rws = "" Then
      rws = "(" + Aaaaa.Text
   Else
      rws = "(" + Aaaaa.Text
   End If
End If

If Aaaaa.Checked = False Then
   rws = ""
End If

If Baaaa.Checked = True Then
   CheckBox1.Checked = True
   close_parenthesis.Checked = True
   If rws = "" Then
      rws = "(" + Baaaa.Text
   Else
      rws = rws & ", " & Baaaa.Text
   End If
End If

If Caaaa.Checked = True Then
   CheckBox1.Checked = True
   close_parenthesis.Checked = True
   If rws = "" Then
      rws = "(" + Caaaa.Text
   Else
      rws = rws & ", " & Caaaa.Text
   End If
End If

If close_parenthesis.Checked = True Then
   If rws = "" Then

   Else
      rws = rws + close_parenthesis.Text
   End If
End If

CheckBox1.Text = rws.ToString
Me.CagayanReplace.PerformClick()
```

I used this code for the changing the `,` to the word `and` inside the parenthesis

```
Dim Strng As String = Me.CheckBox1.Text
'now find the position of last appearing ","
Dim comaposition As Integer
comaposition = Strng.LastIndexOf(",") 'it is zero  based

'if not found, it will return -1 and u can exit, no need to do the work
If comaposition = "-1" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'remove the comma
Dim String_After_Removing_Comma As String
String_After_Removing_Comma = Strng.Remove(comaposition, 1)

'add "and" in the same position where comma was found
Dim final_string As String
final_string = String_After_Removing_Comma.Insert(comaposition, " and ")

'show it on the textbox
CheckBox1.Text = final_string`
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: This kind of sucks - I wish I could do something about it.

Comment: What language is this? You've tagged it [vb.net], but the code isn't VB.NET.

Comment: i use Vb.net 2017

Comment: i used this code to seperate the character that have no #,

Answer (score 0):

This here is not a pretty solution and can be optimized a lot. But it gets the job done:

```
Dim Strfinal As String = "#Cccccc,#Aaaaaa,Aaaaa,Baaaa,Caaaa,#Bbbbbb,Abbbbb,Bbbbbb,Cbbbbb"
Dim splittedString As String() = Strfinal.Split(",")
Dim a As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim newstr As String = ""

For Each str As String In splittedString
        If Not str.Contains("#"c) Then
            a.Add(str)
            Continue For
        End If
        If a.Count > 0 Then
            Dim b = String.Join(",", a)
            Dim i = b.LastIndexOf(","c)
            b = b.Remove(i, 1)
            b = b.Insert(i, " and ")
            newstr += "(" + b + ")," + str
            a.Clear()
        Else
            newstr += str + ","
        End If
Next

If a.Count > 0 Then
        Dim b = String.Join(",", a)
        Dim i = b.LastIndexOf(","c)
        b = b.Remove(i, 1)
        b = b.Insert(i, " and ")
        newstr += "(" + b + ")"
        a.Clear()
End If

newstr = newstr.Replace(",(", " (")

Dim z = newstr.LastIndexOf(",#")
newstr = newstr.Remove(z, 1)
newstr = newstr.Insert(z, " and ")

Console.WriteLine(newstr)
```

Output:

```
#Cccccc,#Aaaaaa (Aaaaa,Baaaa and Caaaa) and #Bbbbbb(Abbbbb,Bbbbbb and Cbbbbb)
```

Check it on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Oup3EN)

Comment: i try your code but when i change:                                                                     
Dim Strfinal As String "#Cccccc,#Aaaaaa,Aaaaa,Baaaa,Caaaa,#Bbbbbb,Abbbbb,Bbbbbb,Cbbbbb"                                                                                                           to Dim Strfinal As String = Me.checkbox13.text                                                messagebox say " StartIndex cannot be less than zero" how to fix it i have no idea

Comment: Checkbox13.text 'to display the output of the checkbox you click